# NuGet - JsonValue 0.5.0 Install-Package Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, nuget, wp7test

I'm trying to get into mobile UI Automation.  I've run into an issue installing the WP7Test package as a part of Windows Phone Automation Framework.  The problem is I can't install JsonValue 0.5.0 which is a dependency of WP7Test.

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'JsonValue 0.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:16
>
> > - Install-Package <<<<  WP7Test
> >
> > > - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
> > > - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

However, shortly before this errors out, I see:

> Successfully installed 'JsonValue 0.5.0'.

I was wondering if anybody has a solution for this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not install through the NuGet Console.  Instead, install through the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You should install WP7Test for Windows C# class library, not for Windows Phone